# MIPS: use label in base-offset addressing

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to use a label as the offset in base-offset addressing mode,
for accessing a global variable in a shellcode-like environment. The base address of the code and data is stored in `$s7`, and I'm trying to do this:

```
# global variable @ offset 20 in code, 
foobar: .word <non-constant value>

# ...

lw $s0, foobar($s7)
```

And then getting the assembler to translate this to `lw $t0, 20($s7)`. Instead, when compiling without special options it takes a detour via `$gp`. Similarily, when using `-mno-abicalls` or `-mno-shared`, the `lw` is translated to:

```
lui     $s0, 0x0
addu    $s0, $s0, $s7
lw      $s0, 20($s0)
```

Is there any way to get it to interpret `foobar` as an immediate value, just like when doing `addiu $t0, $t1, foobar`, which is translated to `addiu $t0, $t1, 20` as expected?

Digging through the docs hasn't yielded anything useful so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to address a compile-time/link-time constant through a runtime value (a register)? That makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: The value is not actually a constant, I just used that as an example!

Comment: Think of it as a global variable - I've updated the question to clarify this!

Comment: But *the address* of the value *is* a constant.

Comment: @EOF: This is position-independent code, but MIPS doesn't have a PC-relative addressing mode.  (Only reg + disp16, which I think is a *signed* displacement, so actually the OP's answer works for labels <= `0x7fff`).

Comment: MIPS is unfortunately quite bad at PIC: even its call instruction (`jal`) is basically an absolute target (except for keeping the high few bits of the old PC value).  https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/PIC_code shows that `jal` in PIC mode is assembled as a pseudo-instruction which loads the branch target from the GOT and uses an indirect `jalr $t9` or whatever.  But you can find your own address with a fully relative `bgezal $0, offset` (because `$0>0` is always true), to get an absolute return address in the link register.  http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

Comment: @PeterCordes Modern MIPS releases have `[d]addiupc` for PIC.

Comment: @EOF the target in question doesn't have PC-relative addressing. @PeterCordes Yes, that's exactly the technique I'm using - determining my address using a `bal` (or `bgezal $0`) and then reading `$ra`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution. For now I'll be using `lw $s0, %lo(foobar)($s7)` which works, as long as the labels are `<= 0xffff` - plus you couldn't do this in a single instruction with a larger offset anyways.